# Travis CI: Trigger build after disabling Build on push

Tags: github, travis-ci

I disabled the `Build Pushes` setting of my project. In the time it was disabled I pushed a commit to GitHub. Now I want to trigger a build for that commit and I can't find a way to do that except for re-enabling the feature and pushing another commit.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new Beta feature which allows you to trigger a build from the browser interface. Its in the list on the RHS in a little box.